# How to add Save As Dialogue Box In Java Class Application

Tags: java, swing, file-io, itext

I have  a pdf generating code that i need to be saved using Save As Dialogue Box but i am not getting how to do it in java class application.Here is my code..

```
PdfWriter writer = null;

    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                fileName));

        document.open();
```

Please suggest me how to add Save as dialoue Box.

Answer (score 2):

Try JFileChooser: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

And then use the path and filename to save in a backend function.